# What's the max of topics I can have on ZeroMQ?

Tags: queue, message-queue, zeromq, distributed-system

I'm new to ZeroMQ ( I've been using SQS so far ).

I would like to build a system where every time a user logs in, they subscribe to a queue. The all the users subscribed to this queue are interested only in messages directed to them.

I read about topic matching. It seems that I could create a pattern like this:

```
development.player.234345345
development.player.453423423
integration.player.345354664
```

And, each worker ( user ) can subscribe to the queue and listen only to the topic they match. i.e. a player 234345345 on the development environment will only subscribe to messages with the topic `development.player.234345345`

Is this true?

And if so, what are the consequences in ZeroMQ?

Is there a limit on how many topic matching I can have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZeroMQ has a very detailed page on how the [internals of topic matching works](http://zeromq.org/whitepapers:message-matching). It looks like you can have as many topics as you want, but topic *matching* incurrs a runtime cost. It's supposed to be extremely fast:

> We believe that application of the above algorithms can give a system
>   that will be able to match or filter a single message in the range of
>   nanoseconds or couple of microseconds even it the case of large amount
>   of different topics and subscriptions.

However, there are some caveats you need to be aware of:

> The inverted bitmap technique thus works by pre-indexing a set of
>   searchable items so that a search request can be resolved with a
>   minimal number of operations.
>
> It is efficient if and only if the set of searchable items is
>   relatively stable with respect to the number of search requests.
>   Otherwise the cost of re-indexing is excessive.

In short, as long as you don't change your subscriptions too often, you should be able to do on the order of thousands of topics at least.

Comment: For topic matching I believe ZeroMQ today uses the trie-based algorithm described by @user3666197.  The page you linked to describes other techniques, but they are not implemented in ZeroMQ.

Answer (score 1):

### A: Yes, you can

The Max. Number? A harder part...

### May would like to read Martin SUSTRIK's post on this:

While ZeroMQ evolves on it's own, Martin, ZeroMQ co-father, has posted on this subject a few interesting facts [**here**](http://nanomsg.org/documentation-zeromq.html), with some further details and design view discussion derrogated [**here**](http://250bpm.com/blog:19)

> **Efficient Subscription Matching**
>
> In ZeroMQ, simple tries are used to store and match PUB/SUB subscriptions. The subscription mechanism was intended for up to 10,000 subscriptions where simple trie works well. However, there are users who use as much as 150,000,000 subscriptions. In such cases there's a need for a more efficient data structure.

Worth reading to have some estimate of where safe-zones are.

### Also worth to know, that not all ZeroMQ versions behave the same way.

Recent API uses **`PUB`**-side topic filtering, which is not automatic for all previous versions, where `SUB`-side filtering was used. Translate that into all the network transport, if all messages, irrespective of their's final destiny are broadcast to all `SUB`-s, just to realise that only one ( user in your use-case ) will match and all the rest will discard the messages, due to topic-filter mismatches.

Thus all your use-cases ought take into account what different ZeroMQ versions ( incl. different non-native language bindings and wrappers ) may 
meet and cooperate on the same playground.

Anyway, ZeroMQ is a great tool, nanomsg being in recent years also worth to monitor and challenge.